# Rate at which an integral approaches infinity

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

If $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \infty$$ what can be said about the rate at which $$\int_1^\infty f(x) \,dx$$ approaches infinity if $f(x) \geq 1$ for all values of $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that can be said is that $$\frac{\int_1^x f(y)dy}{x}\rightarrow \infty.$$ No better lower bound can be given, and nothing can be said about the rate at which this goes to infinity since nothing is given about $f$.  Indeed, you can construct $f$ so that this ratio goes to infinity as slowly, or as quickly as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Is this all the information given? If so, not much.

$f(x)$ could be $|x| + 1$ or $e^x + 1$. These are two pretty different functions, in terms of the rate at which their integrals grow. You would need more information to say  much of anything at all.

Comment: So nothing can be said about it? Is there any lower bound?

Comment: @user1825464: Lower bound on how quickly it diverges? It wouldn't seem so since you can modify B.D.'s examples to $(|x|+1)^{c}$ for $c>0$ and it will diverge slowly for small $c$, or $(e^x+1)^{c_0}$ which can cause the function to diverge quickly.

Comment: The integral can even go to infinity *more slowly* than $f(x)$. Use for example $2xe^{x^2}$.